# How i can run selenium C# test cases in order?

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

i have 10 test cases in c# using selenium but they didn't run in order, how i can order the running of the test cases.

here is my code.

```
[Test]
public void AddLeadWithOneTract()
{
    ClickOnAddNewLead(driver);
    EnterLeadInfo(driver, leadDictionary);
    AddTract(driver);
    EnterTractInfo(driver, tractDictionary, "4n", "2e", "22", "NENE", "1000", "1000", "10");
    SaveTract(driver);
    SaveLeadAndExit(driver);
    TryFindElementById(driver, "R2017000000", 2000);

}

[Test]
public void TestTractInfoValidation()
{
    ClickOnAddNewLead(driver);
    AddTract(driver);
    EnterTractInfo(driver, tractDictionary, "4", "2", "22", "NENE", "-1000", "-1000", "-10");
    SaveTract(driver);
    string alertText = CloseAlertAndGetItsText(driver);
    Assert.IsTrue(alertText.Contains("Please enter a valid Township"));
    Assert.IsTrue(alertText.Contains("Please enter a valid Range"));
    Assert.IsTrue(alertText.Contains("Please set valid asked price"));
    Assert.IsTrue(alertText.Contains("Please enter a valid NRI"));
    Assert.IsTrue(alertText.Contains("Please enter a valid NMA"));
}
```

Comment: What is your testing environment? and which version?

Comment: NUnit.Framework-3.6.0

Answer (score 4):

`Nunit 3.*` has [order attribute](https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/Order-Attribute)

```
[Test, Order(1)]
public void AddLeadWithOneTract()
{
}

[Test, Order(2)]
public void TestTractInfoValidation()
{
}
```